# SQL QUERY SEARCH EACH WORDS, SPLIT SPACE

Tags: sql-server-2005, search

question for sql server query.

I try to create a query for searching every word on a sendence. words are split by a space.

The result contain lines that the value contain every word not at least 1.

sample:

```
DECLARE @DATATABLE TABLE (ID INT,COL1 VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @DATATABLE (ID,COL1) VALUES (1,'ALPHA')
INSERT INTO @DATATABLE (ID,COL1) VALUES (2,'ALPHA BETA')
INSERT INTO @DATATABLE (ID,COL1) VALUES (3,'ALPHA BETA CHARLIE')
INSERT INTO @DATATABLE (ID,COL1) VALUES (4,'ALPHA BETA CHARLIE DELTA')

DECLARE @TESTTABLE AS TABLE (ID INT,COL1 VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @TESTTABLE (ID,COL1) VALUES (1,'ALPHA')             -- RETURN 1,2,3,4
INSERT INTO @TESTTABLE (ID,COL1) VALUES (2,'ALPHA BETA')            -- RETURN 2,3,4
INSERT INTO @TESTTABLE (ID,COL1) VALUES (3,'BETA CHARLIE ALPHA')    -- RETURN 3,4
INSERT INTO @TESTTABLE (ID,COL1) VALUES (4,'BETA DELTA')            -- RETURN 4
INSERT INTO @TESTTABLE (ID,COL1) VALUES (5,'CHARLIE')           -- RETURN 3,4

SELECT * FROM @DATATABLE

DECLARE @I AS INT
SET @I = 1

DECLARE @COUNTLINE AS INT
SET @COUNTLINE = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @TESTTABLE )

DECLARE @CURRENTVALUE AS VARCHAR(MAX)

WHILE(@I <=  @COUNTLINE)
BEGIN

    SET @CURRENTVALUE = (SELECT COL1 FROM @DATATABLE WHERE ID = @I)

    --  **  TODO    **
    -- QUERY SHOULD RETURN EVERY LINE CONTAINING EACH WORD OF THE CURRENT TEST VALUE
    SELECT * FROM @DATATABLE WHERE COL1 LIKE @CURRENTVALUE

    SET @I = @I + 1
END
```

I write "TODO" where I put the first test (saw what that shouldn't do).

I cant create SP or Function.

I look on my side for "with" and "in" or something else.

tank for any tips

and good week end

Comment: You might consider [full text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345119%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) for Sql Server 2005.

Comment: I look at that, I was expected not toching database but if its not a fc or sp, the dba will maybe said yes. Tank you

Comment: I still have faith to found something else.

Comment: did you have a sample that I can use to do full text search. for the moment. I didnt got what I want.

Comment: There is a link in my first comment.

Comment: I know, I just search a way to get a line where each words are. I'm working with the contains, but he didnt return  values if its somewhere inside the value. it acted like an equals without *

Comment: I finally hardcode the query. tank you